# asp textbox Placeholder and autocomplete doesnt work together in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a asp texbox and it has placeholder and jquery autocomplete functionality. Both are working fine in chrome but in IE8 placeholder is not working. In order to make it work I place watermark for placeholder in jquery but then  watermark is displaying but autocomplete is not working. All issue is in IE8:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" CssClass="frmhometxtLocation" placeholder="Locations"
                            onblur="Javascript:FormatLocation();"></asp:TextBox>


        $("#txtLocation")
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .bind("keydown", function (event) {
              if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
          })

          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 1,
              source: function (request, response) {
                  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                locations, extractLast(request.term)));
              },
              focus: function () {
                  // prevent value inserted on focus
                  return false;
              },
              select: function (event, ui) {
                  var terms = split(this.value);
                  // remove the current input
                  terms.pop();
                  // add the selected item
                  terms.push(ui.item.value);
                  // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                  terms.push("");
                  this.value = terms.join(", ");
                  return false;
              }
          });
    });
```

Comment: Please describe the error that you get. Its not rare the javascript code to not work some times with other browsers and need some small changes. Do you have include the correct libraries that are work with IE8 ?

Comment: The error I am getting when using watermark is Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a mistake here and does not including Watermark.min.js. Use Tooltip for Watermark. Now it is working perfectly. Here is the correct code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var locations = ["Anywhere", "Gurgaon", "Delhi", "Noida","Chennai"];
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $("#txtLocation")
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .WaterMark(
        {

        })
          .bind("keydown", function (event) {
              if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
          })

          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 1,
              source: function (request, response) {
                  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last 
                  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                locations, extractLast(request.term)));
              },
              focus: function () {
                  // prevent value inserted on focus
                  return false;
              },
              select: function (event, ui) {
                  var terms = split(this.value);
                  // remove the current input
                  terms.pop();
                  // add the selected item
                  terms.push(ui.item.value);
                  // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                  terms.push("");
                  this.value = terms.join(", ");
                  return false;
              }
          });
    });
 });
 </script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" CssClass="frmhometxtLocation" placeholder="Locations" ToolTip="Locations"
                            onblur="Javascript:FormatLocation();"></asp:TextBox>
```